# Two classes with methods displaying string values in c#

Tags: c#

Define two classes one with a method to display the string "c sharp" and the other to display the string "programming". Write a program using these classes to display a single line output as - "C sharp programming".

I have tried the below code, but couldn't the result.

```
class A
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string one = "c sharp";
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", one, );
    }
}

class B
{
    public void ex2()
    {
        string two = "program";
    }
}
```

Comment: Each class should have a function to print a string, and Main should call those functions.  Obviously, class B will need to be defined first, because Main has to create an instance of it.  You can't use WriteLine if you need multiple things on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment doesn't say whether the two functions have to be static or not.  It's easier if they are:

```
    class B
    {
        static public void ex2()
        {
            Console.Write("programming");
        }
    }
    class A
    {
        public static void ex1()
        {
             Console.Write("C sharp ");
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
             ex1();
             B.ex2();
             Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cSharp = new CSharp();
        var programming = new Programming();
        Console.WriteLine($"{cSharp.Print()} {programming.Print()}");
    }
}

public class CSharp
{
    public string Print()
    {
        return "C sharp";
    }
}

public class Programming
{
    public string Print()
    {
        return "programming";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;

class A
{
public static void Main()
{
    // Create an instance of Class B
    B bInstance = new B();

    // Call the ex2 method from Class B
    string result = bInstance.ex2();

    // Display the combined result
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", "C sharp", result);
 }
}

class B
{
public string ex2()
 {
    // Return the string "programming"
    return "programming";
  }
}
```